# StandardJS linting returns parsing error for static variable

Tags: javascript, eslint, standardjs

I do get an `Parsing error: Unexpected token` linting error for this [line](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/8ed77954959ede6e99cc6b4e08851258cab932b4/examples/with-apollo/lib/with-apollo-client.js#L8) using standardJS. Therefore my CI is failing.

I don't understand what is wrong with this line. How could I fix this?

```
export default (App) => {
  return class Apollo extends React.Component {
    static displayName = 'withApollo(App)' // <--
    static async getInitialProps (ctx) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is standard javascript then the error is that classes can only contain functions, not properties.

The correct syntax should be:

```
class Apollo extends React.Component {
  static async getInitialProps (ctx) {
  // ...
}

Apollo.displayName = 'withApollo(App)';

export default (App) => {
  return Apollo;
}
```

If you are using the proposed (but not yet implemented or approved) ES7/ES8 class properties then maybe `eslint` does not support it yet.

---

If, unlike the original question, you need to use the `App` parameter, Just do it in the function you want to export:

```
class Apollo extends React.Component {
  static async getInitialProps (ctx) {
  // ...
}

export default (App) => {
  Apollo.displayName = `withApollo(${App})`;
  return Apollo;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatly there is `App` to be used inside of the class. Please have a look at the linked original file. How do I have to handle this?

Comment: Nope. The original file does not use `App` at all.